# Curve_Fit not accurate

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

i tried to fit very fluctual data over time as good as possible. So first i smoothed the data which is working fine. The smoothed data I get from this should further be represented from a fit to get out more of the peaks. As you see in the code I want to use an log-tanh function to fit the data. I am well aware that this problem accured in some of the threads already, but I tried them already and the data is also not very small or very big which i know can also cause problems.

The polynomial fit i tried works also pretty good as you see, but it does not eliminate all the wavy values. They cause problems for the following derivative which is very bad.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import diff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import StepModel, LinearModel



def loghypfunc(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    return A*np.log(1+x)+B*np.tanh(C*x)+D*x+E

def expfunc(t, c0, c1, c2, c3):
    return c0+c1*t-c2*np.exp(-c3*t)

def expdecay(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c



path="C:/Users/Sammy/Documents/Masterarbeit WT/CSM und Kriechdaten/Kriechen/Creep_10mN_00008_LC_20210406_2121_DYN.txt"

dataFile = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter='\t', skiprows=2, usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3, 29, 30), dtype=float)
num_rows, num_cols = dataFile.shape

# time column
time = dataFile[:, [0]].transpose()
time = time.flatten()
refTime = time[0]  # get first time in column (reference)
# genullte Testzeit
timeNull = time - refTime
print("time", time)
flatTimeNull = timeNull.flatten()  # jetzt ein 1D array (one row)
##################################################################################
# indent displacement column
indentDis = dataFile[:, [4]].transpose()
indentDis = indentDis.flatten()
indentDis = indentDis - indentDis[0]
# the indendt data has to be smoothed so there is not such a big fluctuation
indentSmooth = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(indentDis, 2001, 3)
# null the indent Smooth data
indentSmooth_Null = indentSmooth - indentSmooth[0]
hind_Smooth_flat = indentSmooth_Null.flatten()  # jetzt ein 1D array
print('indent smooth', indentSmooth)
######################################################################

p0 = [100, 0.1, 100, 0.1]
c, cov = curve_fit(expfunc, time, indentSmooth, p0)
y_indent = expfunc(indentSmooth, *c)


p0 = [70, 0.5, 50, 0.1, 100]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(loghypfunc, time, indentSmooth, p0, maxfev = 10000)
y_indentTan = loghypfunc(indentSmooth, *popt)

modelh_t = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(time, indentSmooth, 8))

plt.plot(time, indentSmooth, 'r', label="Data smoothed")
plt.scatter(time, modelh_t(time), s=0.1, label="Polyfit")
plt.plot(time, y_indentTan, label="Curve fit Tangens function")
plt.plot(time, y_indent, label="Curve fit exp function")
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("indent")

plt.show()
```

These are the two arrays i get the data from

```
time [  6.299596   6.349592   6.399589 ... 608.0109   608.060897 608.110894] 
indent smooth [120.81411822 121.07093706 121.32748184 ... 476.78825661 476.89357473 476.99915287]
```

Here the plots
[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S92Wx.jpg)

The question for me now is how to fix it. Is it because of the false optimizied parameters to fit? But python should do that automatic sufficiently good i guess?
My second guess was that the data is timed to compact along this axes, as the array is about 12000 values long. Could this be a reason?

I would be very grateful for any kind of advices regarding the fits.

Regards
Hndrx

Comment: Did you try with more robust `lmfit`? https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I heard about it but was uncertain if it could help me, i will give it a try

Comment: You were right. It worked much better with lmfit! Do you have an explanation why this is more robust?

Comment: There are many fitting packages in python, `lmfit` is mid-level based on `scipy.optimize` but uses likelihood. You can find here some https://indico.cern.ch/event/834210/contributions/3539146/attachments/1906327/3148396/2019-09-11_Python_Modeling.pdf